# How to prevent duplicating csv file in database when I import it using laravel?

Tags: database, laravel, csv, import

I still didn't find the answer for this problem, I'm gonna to be crazy because of it. Please help in any one know how to prevent duplicating when I import CSV file to the database using laravel when I run my code through reloading the web browser

I tried to prevent duplicating through using function in laravel called updateOrInsert but it dosn't work

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use DB;


class CSVController extends Controller 
{
static function parseCsv($csvFile) 
{
    $products = []; 
    if (($handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r')) !== false)  {
    if (($firstRow = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ';' )) !== false) {
        //$firstRow = str_replace(" ", "_",$firstRow);
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ';')) !== false) {
        if (count($firstRow) !== count($row)) {
            return false;
        } 

        $product = [];
        $product = array_combine($firstRow, $row);
        array_push($products, $product); 
    }     
    }
        fclose($handle);
    }     
    return $products; 
}

public function importCsv()
{    
    $products = $this::parseCsv('data.csv');
    var_dump($products);

    if (!empty($products)) {

        foreach($products as $product) {
            Product::create($product);  
        }
    }

    DB::table('products')
        ->updateOrInsert(
        ['id' => '1073', 'name' => 'Jonathan', 'age' => '28','job' => 'consult','city' => 'Rome','hobby' => 'horses'],
        ['name' => 'Jonathan', 'age' => '28','job' => 'consult','city' => 'Sanaa','hobby' => 'horses']
    );

    return $this->parseCsv('data.csv');
}    
}
```

Comment: it is not clear your `importCsv()` function firstly you are checking if `$products` is not empty then create new product in database. But after that why you are adding `DB::table('products')` statement. That is confusing.

Comment: importCsv() functions is used for importing my csv file to the database. This part of the code who is Product::create($product); it's laravel function called Create and used to insert the CSV file to the DB. About the other part who is DB::table('products') it's the function who I wanted to ask about. It's for updating a record in the DB, so I can after that to prevent duplicating when I reload my code through the web browser. But it dosn't work. I'm gonna to be crazy because of . Please help if you know... thanks in advance